# Pointer to register value in array C

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, stm32

I'm working with an STM32F303RE.
I have the following array:

```
int regvals[] = { GPIOA->MODER, GPIOA->OTYPER, GPIOA->OSPEEDR, GPIOA->PUPDR, GPIOA->IDR, GPIOA->ODR, GPIOA->BSRR, GPIOA->LCKR, GPIOA->AFR, GPIOA->AFR, GPIOA->BRR };
```

Now I want to write to one of these registers.
For that I have the following code:

```
int *writeVal;
writeVal = &regvals[index];
*writeVal = value;
```

where value is an int with the value i want to set.

When reading the value of the register afterwards it still remains the same as before "writing" it. So for some reason the value is not being set in the register.

Comment: **What does "doesn't work" mean?** "Doesn't work" is an inadequate description for us to understand the problem.  What happened when you tried it?  Did you get an error message? If you did get an error, paste the entire message instead of paraphrasing. Did you get incorrect results?  Did you get *no* results?  If the results were incorrect, what made them incorrect?  What were you expecting instead?  Did you get *any* correct results?  If so, what were they?  Don't make us guess.

Comment: You initialize the `int` array with current values of registers. They are not addresses and for that reason `&regvals[index]` is the address of value, not the register.

Comment: @Andy Lester I don't get any error message but incorrect results. The value of the register is not being set and when reading it afterwards is still the same as before.

Comment: @i486 with the &regvals[index] i want to set the address of the writeVal pointer to the same as the register has to set that value.

Comment: @MischaBinder are you able to set a register value by any other method?

Comment: @MischaBinder You will modify the value of corresponding `regvals[index]`, not the real register. Is this OK?

Comment: @Jabberwocky Yes. When user GPIOA->MODER = value; as example. But that's not what I want.

Comment: @MischaBinder i486's comment looks like the answer

Comment: @i486 I want to modify the value of the real register. Not that in the array. The array should just be used to identify which register should be modified.

Comment: @MischaBinder I understand the idea. What is `GPIOA->MODER`? I guess it is bitfields in structure. If this is it, then you cannot get the address of bit fields.

Comment: Ohh okey. So I should like store the registers addresses in the array instead of the values? You have an example how to do that? @i486

Comment: Just for the record it's a jolly bad idea to dump variously mildly related GPIO registers in one big mysterious array. Don't take something clear and readable and turn it into an unreadable mess...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. This code does not do what you think. It reads once the values of the registers (during initialization)  and then it is just integer array not related to the hardware registers.

`&regvals[index]` is just referencing the element of this integer array not related to the hardware register.

if you want to keep references to the registers you want:

```
volatile uint32_t *regrefs[] = { &GPIOA->MODER, &GPIOA->OTYPER, &GPIOA->OSPEEDR, &GPIOA->PUPDR, &GPIOA->IDR, &GPIOA->ODR, &GPIOA->BSRR, &GPIOA->LCKR, &GPIOA->AFR, &GPIOA->AFR, &GPIOA->BRR };
```

```
volatile uint32_t *writeVal;
writeVal = regrefs[index];
*writeVal = value;
```

Remember that `BSRR` & `BRR` registers are **write only**

Comment: Any comment silent DV-ter. Or it is just the comment revenge :)

Comment: I think volatile in `volatile uint32_t *regrefs[]` is not necessary. I upvoted BTW.

Comment: Hardware registers are side effect prone and have to be `volatile` If you read the register twice in the row it could be changed by hardware in the meantime.

Comment: Sure, but `volatile uint32_t *regrefs[] = { &GPIOA->MODER, &GPIOA->OTYPE,...` doesn't even read the hardware registers. It just initializes the `regrefs` array with the HW register's _addresses_.

Comment: Doesn't ST libs provide a struct-based register map for the whole GPIO peripheral anyway? Why would you ever make an array like this?

Comment: @Jabberwocky If you don't use `volatile`, a compiler can assume that in case of `if(regrefs[n]==foo) ... if(regrefs[n]==bar)`, we can merrily remove the `if(regrefs[n]==bar)` from the source code entirely, since no pointer that alias the object that `regref` points at did a write access to that object since `if(regrefs[n]==foo)` was executed. So this answer is correct and skipping `volatile` might cause mayham during code generation.

Comment: @Lundin but `regrefs[n]` doesn't read from the HW register. I don't get it. What am I missing?

Comment: @Jabberwocky Sorry should have been `*regrefs[n]`.

Comment: @Lundin I do not know what OP needs it for.

Comment: Anyway, I think this whole discussion is pointless since the code without `volatile` isn't even valid C. From simple assignment constraints, emphasis mine: "the left operand has atomic, qualified, or unqualified pointer type,...  and the type pointed
to by **the left has all the qualifiers of the type pointed to by the right**;"